# javascript Onclick apply tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using rich text editor , and i am trying to add the code tag feature to it.
The editor has 2 buttons right now.
one is underline and another one is code

When i select the text and click underline button, the selected text will get underlined 
but when i select the text and click code button, it is not working.

I have already added the code tag option, but it is not working

code:

```
document.writeln('<td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'underline.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Underline" title="Underline" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'underline\', \'\')"></td>');
document.writeln('<td><img class="rteImage" src="' + imagesPath + 'code.gif" width="25" height="24" alt="Code" title="Code" onClick="rteCommand(\'' + rte + '\', \'code\', \'\')"></td>');
```

In above code i have used Underling and code tag for underline and code button
 both are using same javascript function. The underline is working properly but when i select the code section & click code button, it is not working

Javascript function code:

```
function rteCommand(rte, command, option) {
    //function to perform command
    var oRTE;
    if (document.all) {
        oRTE = frames[rte];
    } else {
        oRTE = document.getElementById(rte).contentWindow;
    }
    alert(command);

    try {
        oRTE.focus();
        oRTE.document.execCommand(command, false, option);
        oRTE.focus();
    } catch (e) {
    }
}
```

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Since the first one is working I think you should create a separate function to handle the "Code" button